# Forms authentication in asp.net web forms and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, asp.net-identity

I am trying to rebuild existing asp.net web forms and create a new mvc app. I am stuck on authenticating users.

In web forms app I was using

```
public class UserPrincipal : System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
public class UserIdentity : System.Security.Principal.IIdentity
```

to declare custom UserPrincipal and UserIdentity classes.

During login process I was using

```
UserPrincipal mpUser = new UserPrincipal(userID);
if (mpUser != null)
                {
                    Context.User = mpUser;
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                        userID.ToString(),
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                        false,
                       ((UserIdentity)Context.User.Identity).IdentityRolesToString(userID)
                        );

string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

Is authentication process still the same. I found a lot of stuff about SimpleMembership, Basic Membership, ASP.NET Membership, but I am confused is this technique obsolete or there is a new recommended way to do this?

Comment: This is perfectly fine. There are other, newer approaches but sticking with the old, good approach is still ok.

Comment: @WiktorZychla could you point out what newer approaches actually extends this approach?

Comment: The Identity 2.0 is a newer approach. My problem with it is that there are two strongly separate frameworks: the identity itself which is a very simple approach to describing users/roles/claims with interfaces and a default entity framework implementation and the actual cookie/authentication stuff that comes from owin. These two can be used separately and only the owin part is interesting.